# If $\lim \limits_{x\to \infty} f'(x)=\ell$ then find $ \lim\limits _{x \to \infty} \frac{f(6x)}{x}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable.  If $\lim _{x\to \infty} f'(x)=\ell$  for real number $\ell$, then find $$ \lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{f(6x)}{x}$$

Mt attempt:
By L'Hospital rule
$$\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{f(6x)}{x}=6\lim _{x \to \infty} f'(6x)=6\ell.$$ Am I right?

Comment: You might want to read what you wrote.

Comment: $L$ is the limit of $f'(x)$ while you use the limit of $f'(6x)$. You should consider to rewrite your solution. Notice that if $x\to\infty$ then $6x\to\infty$ either...

Comment: @suresh I re-dited your question. Is it OK?

Comment: to use L'Hospital rule you need that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(6x)\longrightarrow\pm\infty$

Comment: @Holo No, that's not needed, as long as the denominator has infinite limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Without Hospital** Only Using the fundamental theorem of Calculus we have,

$$f(6x) =f(0) +\int_0^x 6f'(6t)dt\overset{t=xu}{=}f(0) +x\int_0^1 6f'(6\color{blue}{xu})dt,~~ x>0.$$

Thus, since $[0,1]$ is compact and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)= \ell$  we get,
$$\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{f(6x)}{x}  =\lim _{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{f(0)}{x}+ 6\int_0^1 f'(6\color{blue}{xu})du\right)  =6\ell$$

Comment: @Surb. Because here, [0,1] is compact it is writen there.